# O que strpos() retorna quando o valor procurado não é encontrado?

Tags: php

Tenho um código que está me causando uma dúvida quando ao retorno do método `strpos()` do PHP.

Vejam o que é retornado **quando o valor procurado é encontrado**:

```
$string = "vermelho";
$result = strpos($string, "vermelho"); 

echo $result . "<br>";

if($result == false)
{
    echo "Retornou false<br>";      
}

if($result == "")
{
    echo "Retornou vazio<br>";      
}

if($result == 0)
{
    echo "Retornou zero<br>";       
}

if($result == "0")
{
    echo "Retornou zero<br>";       
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora vejam o que é retornado **quando o valor é não encontrado**:

```
$string = "vermelho";
$result = strpos($string, "azul"); 

echo $result."<br>";


if($result == false)
{
    echo "Retornou false<br>";      
}

if($result == "")
{
    echo "Retornou vazio<br>";      
}

if($result == 0)
{
    echo "Retornou zero<br>";       
}

if($result == "0")
{
    echo "Retornou zero<br>";       
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O retorno é praticamente o mesmo e entra em todas as condições para ambos os casos acima.

Na **documentação** diz:

> Se needle não for encontrado, strpos() irá retornar o boolean FALSE.

`FALSE` não seria igual a `0`?

Eu vi um código no qual é feito uma comparação do resultado do `strpos()` com `-1`. Em algum caso é retornado `-1` do `strpos()`?

Comment: Na documentação comenta os retornos da função. Se o caracter buscado estiver na primeira posição ele retorna zero, o PHP converte o zero para false, nesse cenário vc deve comparar usando o `===` que verifica se tipo e valor são iguais

Comment: Mas se eu coloco uma String para ser buscada, como é achada a posição dessa string dentro da outra string ? Por exemplo, se eu colocar "a" pra ser procurado em "azul" tá certo retornar 0, pois o caracter foi encontrado na primeira posição. Porém, se eu colocar "azul" para ser procurado em "azul", como é retornado 0 nesse caso ?

Comment: `strpos` procura pela primeira ocorrência de uma string dentro de outra e retorna a posição onde esta ocorrência começa. `strpos("azul", "a")` retorna 0 porque a posição 0 é a primeira ocorrência de "a" em "azul". `strpos("azul", "az")` também retorna 0, pois é nessa posição que **começa** a primeira ocorrência de "az" dentro de "azul". Então `strpos("azul", "azul")` tb retorna zero pelo mesmo motivo

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, pessoal.

Comment: Strpos() irá retornar FALSE. Para mais informações, consulte a documentação do php. [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação de `strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), a função recebe duas strings (que lá são chamadas de "palheiro" e "agulha") e o retorno é (em tradução livre):

> *A posição onde a agulha se encontra, relativa ao início da string palheiro.*
>   *Retorna FALSE se a agulha não for encontrada.*

Então basicamente ela retorna a posição da string na qual a primeira ocorrência da substring se inicia. Por exemplo, `strpos("azul", "az")` retorna `0` porque é na posição zero de "azul" que começa a primeira ocorrência de "az". O mesmo vale para `strpos("azul", "a")` e `strpos("azul", "azul")`, o retorno de ambas também é `0`.

E quando a substring não ocorre dentro da string, o retorno é `FALSE`. Ou seja, o retorno pode ser tanto um número inteiro quanto um *booleano*. Por exemplo, para o código abaixo:

```
var_dump(strpos("azul", "az")); // retorna 0
var_dump(strpos("azul", "xyz")); // retorna FALSE
```

A saída é:

```
int(0)
bool(false)
```

---

O problema começa na hora de verificar o valor retornado. Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), o operador `==` que você usou compara os operandos depois de aplicar o [*type juggling*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). Isso quer dizer que se você comparar `0 == FALSE`, eles serão considerados iguais (consulte a [tabela de comparação "frouxa"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose)).

Por isso, o código abaixo imprime "X":

```
if (0 == FALSE) {
    echo "X"; // imprime X
} else {
    echo "Y";
}
```

Já se usarmos o operador `===`, não é feito o *type juggling*, e são seguidas as [regras de comparação estrita](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#type.comparisons-strict), que também verifica se os operandos são do mesmo tipo. Ou seja, o código abaixo imprime "Y":

```
if (0 === FALSE) {
    echo "X";
} else {
    echo "Y"; // imprime Y
}
```

O mesmo vale para os outros testes que você fez. Tanto a string vazia (`""`) quanto a string `"0"`, quando comparadas com `==`, são consideradas iguais a `FALSE` (consulte a [tabela de comparação "frouxa"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) já citada acima).

---

Portanto, o problema é a forma como você está verificando o retorno. Inclusive, a própria [documentação de `strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) diz para usar o operador `===` para verificar o retorno desta função. Ex:

```
$result = strpos("azul", "az");

if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "Não foi encontrada nenhuma ocorrência";
} else {
    echo "Encontrada ocorrência na posição $result";
}
```

Ou, se quiser verificar que uma posição específica foi encontrada, poderia ser algo do tipo:

```
if ($result === 0) {
    echo "Encontrada ocorrência no início da string";
} else if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "Não foi encontrada nenhuma ocorrência";
} else {
    echo "Encontrada ocorrência, mas não no início da string (posição $result)";
}
```

---

Quanto a comparar o retorno com `-1`, é uma forma alternativa [sugerida na documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#80363). Mas não é para comparar se o retorno é **igual** a `-1` (pois a documentação não menciona nenhum caso em que `strpos` retorna `-1`), e sim se o valor retornado é **maior** que `-1`. Isso porque ao verificar se `FALSE` é maior que `-1`, o resultado será falso:

```
if (FALSE > -1) {
    echo "X";
} else {
    echo "Y"; // imprime Y
}
```

Portanto, uma outra forma de verificar o retorno é:

```
$result = strpos($string1, $string2);

if ($result > -1) {
    echo "Encontrada ocorrência, na posição $result";
} else {
    echo "Não foi encontrada nenhuma ocorrência";
}
```

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Quando você fizer comparação, é recomendado que faça com três iguais (===). Assim, você compara o valor da variável e o tipo também. Do jeito que você escreveu (==), os valores zero, string vazia e false, sempre será false, mas se fizer a comparação com === o PHP vai comparar o tipo da variável também.

```
if($result === false)
{
    echo "Retornou false<br>";      
}

if($result === "")
{
    echo "Retornou vazio<br>";      
}

if($result === 0)
{
    echo "Retornou zero<br>";       
}

if($result === "0")
{
    echo "Retornou zero<br>";       
}
```